# LINQ query for the Date Occurrence

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert this SQL query into LINQ query.

```
SQL:

SELECT  Name,
        Date,
        NextDate,
        DATEDIFF("D", Date, NextDate)
FROM    (   SELECT    Name,    

                    Date,
                    (   SELECT  MIN(Date) 
                        FROM    DailyJobCount T2
                        WHERE   T2.Name = T1.Name
                        AND     T2.Date > T1.Date AND T2.id ='NOT RUN' AND T1.id ='NOT RUN'
                    ) AS NextDate
            FROM    DailyJobCount T1   
        ) AS T  
        where Date >= '03-03-2015' and Date <='03-03-2016' 
        group by T.Name, Date,NextDate
```

I have tried like,

```
 var deviation = (from record in _db.DailyJobCount
    where
        record.Date >= StartTime && record.Date <= EndTime && record.IsActive.Equals(true) &&
        record.jobid == "NOT RUN"
    group new {record} by new
{
    record.Name, record.Date
}
into rec
    select new
    {
        Name = rec.Key.Name,
        Diff = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day",StartTime, NextDate ),


    }
    );
```

But it gives error in "NextDate" and also its not complete LINQ QUery. I really have no idea for this. Can you please suggest regarding this.Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this variant:

**LINQ:**

```
var dateFrom = new DateTime(2015, 03, 03);
var dateTo = new DateTime(2016, 03, 03);
var id = "NOT RUN";

var query = from item1 in _db.DailyJobCounts
            where item1.Date >= dateFrom && item1.Date <= dateTo
            from item2 in _db.DailyJobCounts
            where item1.Name == item2.Name && item1.Date < item2.Date && item1.id == id && item2.Name == id
            group new { item1, item2 } by new { item1.Name, item1.Date } into subGroup
            select new
            {
                subGroup.Key.Name,
                subGroup.Key.Date,
                NextDate = subGroup.Min(x => x.item2.Date),
            } into result                        
            select new
            {
                result.Name,
                result.Date,
                result.NextDate,
                Diff = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", result.Date, result.NextDate),
            };

var answer = query.ToList();
```

**T-SQL:**

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [Name], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Date], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
    DATEDIFF(day, [GroupBy1].[K1], [GroupBy1].[A1]) AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [K1], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [K2], 
        MIN([Extent2].[Date]) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[DailyJobCounts] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DailyJobCounts] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[Name] = [Extent2].[Name]) OR (([Extent1].[Name] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Name] IS NULL))
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Date] >= 03.03.2015 0:00:00) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= 03.03.2016 0:00:00) AND ([Extent1].[Date] < [Extent2].[Date]) AND ([Extent1].[id] = 'NOT RUN') AND (([Extent2].[Name] = 'NOT RUN') OR (([Extent2].[Name] IS NULL) AND ('NOT RUN' IS NULL)))
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[Date], [Extent1].[Name]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: In sql it automatically takes the NextDate as a function
But how to use the Nextdate in LINQ

Comment: I changed my answer several times, check newest one and compare your sql script with my. I tried to execute this query on empty table and I have no errors. Where exactly you have error at what row?

Comment: Here NextDate is not a column name . We have to get the NextDate as a dynamic one. To find the nextdate for the values

Comment: Yes, i made mistake at first time, check now my recent solution - NextDate  is calculated as you said: `NextDate = subGroup.Min(x => x.item2.Date)`

Comment: GREAT!!, Thanks, It works file. I have one more doubt. How to get the Values fromDiff ?

Comment: What values do you want, concretely?

Comment: Ya , me too have a doubt in that. How to get the Diff values. Its stored as List means . How to get that values and also how to pass that values into some other method

Comment: I not understand, you can write something like this: `var val = answer.First().Diff`. Is it what you asked about?

Comment: If i need to pass the Diff value into some method like sample () means, How can I able to get the Diff from the query and how to pass that value.

Comment: I have already wrote it: `sample(answer.First().Diff)` - it will pass firts(for example) Diff value to method as argument.

Comment: It just passes the first value in the list (Diff) right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105990/discussion-between-sara-and-slava-utesinov).